Getting error 500 PHPMailer with office365 smtp
This is the first time I'm using PHPMailer and I'm getting error 500 when I send a message through the form on my website.
I also tried port number 587 but I get the same error.
Probably I've set something wrong in the server configuration.
What username and password should I put? The credentials of the Microsoft account or just the email and password of the address you want to send emails with?
At this point I am a bit confused.
Also regarding the tls. The person who set up the environment and sent me the credentials, told me to only use TLS version 1.2. Is this something that I can set on the code or that can cause the error 500?
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    // server configuration
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com'; // host server smtp
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'username@username.it'; // what username? the email address?
    $mail->Password   = 'password'; // smtp pss
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port       = 25; // tcp port for smtp

    // recipients
    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@email.it', 'Company Name'); // should this be the same as the username?
    $mail->addAddress('additionaladdress@email.it', 'Mary'); is this and extra email address where I want receive the data
    $mail->addAddress('additionaladdress@email.it', 'Jhon');

    // email contents
    $mail->isHTML(true); // html email format
    $mail->Subject = 'New message from $name';
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}


Check your error logs, or enable errors, because error 500 is probably caused by a simple syntax error. For instance, forgetting to comment out a comment?

check that test message going from here: https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test    using your credentails or not? if going then you have some issue in your code.

@Death-is-the-real-truth yes it was a typo here.

@Death-is-the-real-truth I ran a test and I get: << 554 5.2.252 SendAsDenied; no-reply@mail.it not allowed to send as othermail@mail.it;
The username provided me is the no-reply... and the setFrom is othermail...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784431/unable-to-send-smtp-mails-using-office365-settings?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top

Rolled back your edit because the syntax error you removed caused the error 500 which you are asking about.

@DarkBee yeah. "From Email Address" and "SMTP Username" have to be the same. I changed them, and still got the error.

Is the password you've received for the credentials an app password or your actual (mailbox) password? Because I think you need to use an app password for this
